# Как понимать такое использование for и if в Python?

Tags: python, синтаксис

Cобствено, непонятная строка:

```
l = [i for i in A[1:] if i <= m]
```

Что делает i for i в срезе массива и как работает if?

Как я понимаю для каждого i в срезе массива `A[1:len(A)-1]` проверяется условие и при истине оно возвращает элемент в список.

Код целиком, пример бинарного поиска из книги «Грокаем Алгоритмы», ошибок не кидает:

```py
def qsort(A):
    if len(A) < 2: return A
    pivot = A[0]
    l = [i for i in A[1:] if i <= pivot] # else pass?
    r = [i for i in A[1:] if i > pivot]
    return qsort(l) + [pivot] + qsort(r)
```

Comment: Правильно понимаете, добавить к вашему пониманию вроде бы нечего

Comment: Это называется списковое включение https://python-scripts.com/for-in-one-line

Answer (score 4):

Эта конструкция называется [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Аналогичные генераторы есть для <strike>tuple</strike>, set, map:

```py
setOfEven = { x for x in range(1000) if x%2 == 0 }
dictOddSquares = { x : x*x for x in range(1000) if x%2 == 1 }
```

УТОЧНЕНИЕ

Про tuple я был не прав, виноват. В Python можно написать вот такой текст:

```py
t = ( x*x for x in range(10) )
```

Это выглядит как List Comprehension, только для tuple, поэтому я всегда это воспринимал именно как tuple comprehension. Но на самом деле это иная конструкция, которая называется [Generator Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator-expression)

Присваивание выше создаёт генератор, эквивалентный генератору

```py
def _gen():
  for x in range(10):
    yield x*x

t = _gen()
```

только в одну строчку. *Как будто tuple comprehension* выглядит присваивание

```py
t = tuple( x*x for x in range(10) )
```

но на самом деле это вызов конструктора `tuple` c генератором `x*x for x in range(10)` в качестве аргумента.

Comment: для tuple – нет

Comment: Верно. Спасибо за комментарий. Обновил ответ.